# mysqldump does want to excute the command

Tags: mysql

I tried to restore my db (18Mo) with that

```
mysqldump -u c1_forum -p c1_clic_forum > data-dump.sql
```

insert my password
but nothing happen.

any idea ?

Comment: mysqldump is only for taking backup, for restore syntax is `mysql -u user -p db_name < dumpfile`

Comment: Also you may have just overwritten your backup file.